# TypeError: User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'confirm_password'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to add `password` field and `confirm_password` field to my `UserSerializer`. I wrote a function called `create` to create a hashes password for my `password` field but before it can create the hashes password I want it to make sure that `confirm_password` and `password` are matched. The code works fine if I remove the `confirm_password` field. What is the problem?

[ Updated ]

My serializers.py

```
# serializer define the API representation
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    # password field
    password = serializers.CharField(
        write_only = True,
        required = True,
        help_text = 'Enter password',
        style = {'input_type': 'password'}
    )
    
    # confirm password field
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(
        write_only = True,
        required = True,
        help_text = 'Enter confirm password',
        style = {'input_type': 'password'}
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'url', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',
            'password', 'confirm_password', 'is_staff'
        ]
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        if validated_data.get('password') != validated_data.get('confirm_password'):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Those password don't match") 

        elif validated_data.get('password') == validated_data.get('confirm_password'):
            validated_data['password'] = make_password(
                validated_data.get('password')
            )

        return super(UserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

error I got

```
TypeError: User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'confirm_password'

[20/Aug/2020 16:15:44] "POST /users/ HTTP/1.1" 500 168152
```

error I got in browser

```
TypeError at /users/
Got a `TypeError` when calling `User.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `User.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the UserSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
```

I can edit the question if you need more detail. Ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to save field `confirm_password` into your `User` model. I believe that this field is used only to confirm password, but `User` model doesn't have this field really.

Try to pop this field from `validated_data` before saving:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    if validated_data.get('password') != validated_data.get('confirm_password'):
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Those password don't match") 

    elif validated_data.get('password') == validated_data.get('confirm_password'):
        validated_data['password'] = make_password(
                validated_data.get('password')
            )

    validated_data.pop('confirm_password') # add this
    return super(UserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

P.S. Validation is usually done in `validate()` method, not in `create()`.

Comment: when I add that 1 line it gave me this error `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username`

Comment: This is another error, because the user with this username already exists. Probably you have to add uniqueness to username in serializer.

Comment: Or just add `username` in `Meta.fields` if it's unique in your `User` model. Maybe this will help. Create new question about it or at least add your `User` model in question.

Comment: It works by adding `username` to `fields=[ ]`! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[from_the_docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm).

Try using `password1` and `password2` instead of `password` and `confirm_passowrd` as password field names, respectively.

Comment: try making **confirm_password** field **read_only**.

Comment: @from_the_docs confirm_password is not read_only field. read_only field is sent in response.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing validation in `create` method. This is not right approach. This should be done in `is_valid` or `validate` method of serializer. Your `create` method should look like this

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    # confirm_password should not be sent to create as it is not part of User model
    validated_data.pop('confirm_password', None)
    return super(UserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

Comment: when I add that 1 line it gave me this error `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username`

Comment: Thats your data issue. You should perform all validation in your validation methods. like is password same, is user with this email already exists or not etc. When you will call serializer.save() first validation will run. After that, code will enter in create method. If user with that email already exists, it will not enter in create method.